# WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter not found

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

My build.gradle contains:

```
compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:4.1.3.RELEASE')
```

Did a "refresh all gradle projects" (im using IntelliJ!)

When i want to extend `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` it says "Create class ...."

The namespace where `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` should be is also not found...

See http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html

Comment: I faced same problem with eclipse , I added  spring-security-config in build.gradle , but still eclipse could not found the class. Then I just copied the the entire class path and added as import -- import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;  It worked this way.

Answer (score 8):

add maven dependency spring config like this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

or download jar and connect to your project

Answer (score 3):

I faced this issue when I added the wrong dependency package from maven. By mistake, I added `spring-security-web` instead of `spring-boot-starter-security`.

Please add

> `spring-boot-starter-security`

and it will work :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can do this :

```
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Add these dependencies in the pom file in the maven project.
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a newer version (> 5.7.0) of `spring-boot` and hence `spring-boot-starter-security`, the class `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated. See the notes on the GitHub [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/10822). Now on you need to declare beans for each type of component (web, http, etc) that you are trying to configure security for.